# Would a large number of people simultaneously turning on a load of 3 kW be sufficient to bring down the electricity grid across 500 sq km?

Tags: internal-consistency, electricity

Sabotaging the electric network is kind of a well established scheme: find a node of the network, put some explosive on the pole and take it down (or the like). The network is gone for a while.

Now imagine that this organization wants to avoid using explosives and plans to do the following: a large set of conjureds agrees on switching on a high power electric device in their houses (let's say an electric oven or a water boiler, drawing at least 3 kW) at the very same time, to the split second.

Is this a realistic plan to take down the network on (at least) an urbanized area of about 500 square km?

(background info: when I was at the University during a lecture on electricity generation the professor told us that in the '80es a comedian, during a TV show, proposed to complain against the government by switching off the TV when he said to do so. The professor claimed that if he had done it, it would have caused a nationwide blackout.)

Comment: Really not sure what you mean. If you want to overload the network, even a basic distribution network, you're off by a factor of 100

Comment: How many people switching on heavy loads? Regardless, 3kW each is nothing. Grids are far too over-engineered for that, except in sparsely populated rural areas, perhaps.

Comment: What about going the other way around, pumping electricity back into the system? A lot of houses are equipped with solar panels and energy storage systems. If these systems would blow their electricity back into the network at one single moment, it would possibly produce a large peak forcing the network to reroute or shutdown. Probably.

Comment: Can't put as an answer as an anecdote - but supposedly when Coronation Street was one of the most popular tv show in the UK, almost half the population would go and turn on their kettle in the minutes after the episode. While I never heard of it taking the grid down, they had to compensate by pushing the power up every day before it ended...

Comment: @Rycochet - it wasn't the kettles that was the problem.  It was everyone going to the loo, flushing it, and causing the pumping stations to all switch on.

Comment: @MartinBonner - Just found the right name for this - "TV pickup" - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TV_pickup (including references) :-)

Comment: Will your rubes be willing to all install a special appliance in their homes - say, a tampered-with washing machine that's capable of much greater electrical pull than it needs? At the right time, they all activate this particular capacity.

Or better yet, activate it remotely (yay Internet of Things!).

Comment: Is this already listed on [What-If](https://what-if.xkcd.com/) ?? :-)

Comment: It's quite plausible that this would take down some local parts of the grid. The company I work for has a single device which consumes about 35MW of power when it's running (it usually runs for an hour or two at a time). We have a special "red telephone" to the nearest power station to warn them when we are planning to use it, to avoid this problem - and they can refuse permission to run it if they can't handle the situation. That's only equivalent to a few thousand kettles.

Comment: @alephzero Out of curiosity, what is this device? Is it a doom hyperlaser, because your employer is a mad scientist?

Comment: If the grid can produce the electricity then it would just step up in a couple seconds.   Grid does just fine with under capacity.    Turn off at the same time would be harder on the grid but I suspect a proper grid would have safe guards to dump electricity.

Comment: How long does it have to be down for? It's relatively easy to crash it with a surge in demand, but there are easily-started power stations (typically hydropower) that can step up to the demand very quickly (half a minute). Unless you top what these can provide, forcing the grid to start the slower ones (coal or even nuclear) the power won't stay down for more than a minute.

Comment: This seems related to my fear of a cyberattack on IoT devices ("the 's' in IoT stands for security"): if you can break into millions of thermostats and simultaneously add or shed the load of millions of AC units, that could maybe cause problems.

Comment: Keep in mind it's not just a single increase in load you can use. If you can synchronize switching precisely, there are all sorts of things you can do with reflections, resonances, etc.

Comment: I've worked somewhere with a wind tunnel that was 60 MW, so you would need over 20,000 kettles for a similar load. There were other tunnels on the same site, but they weren't all used at the same time because of the power demands. There was also a gas turbine powered generating station on site, but it still required co-ordination with the national grid. Mostly it was "we won't run it now because the peak electricity costs are so much higher" rather than "the grid can't cope if we run it now".
http://www.bahg.org.uk/8X8.htm
http://www.pprune.org/archive/index.php/t-399064.html

Answer (score 38, accepted):

## Yes and No

Would you believe this occurs at a predictable time every day in the UK?

During the break at the end of popular soap operas a significant percentage of the population of the UK puts the kettle on. Total load spike on the system can reach 3GW, equivalent to approximately 1.8kW load per household for around [1.75 million kettles at almost exactly the same moment](http://www.geek.com/geek-cetera/tea-time-in-britain-causes-predictable-massive-surge-in-electricity-demand-1535023/)<sup>1</sup>.

This is a known factor and you can set your watch by the power surges relating to it. Power stations are on standby, more power is made available in France to cover the spike.

However this is a known effect at a known time and the system is geared up to cope with it. Dropping a 3GW load onto the national grid without preparation would likely knock large sections out.

*<sup>1</sup>[BBC video source](http://www.bbc.co.uk/britainfromabove/stories/people/teatimebritain.shtml) probably not available outside the UK*

Comment: *"Average load 1.8kW per household."* I doubt that this is completely accurate as stated. The draw by the average kettle may be 1.8 kW, but suppose all households have one kettle each, and that 60% of households turn on their kettles; then the average load increase is about 1.1 kW per household. And 60% is probably *quite high* even for a popular soap opera. 30% may be more reasonable, which would mean that the individual kettles need to draw around 6 kW for the average load increase to be *1.8 kW per household*. A load increase of 1.8 kW *per household that turns on the kettle* is reasonable.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling, the overall 3GW figure is a quote from a load balancing engineer at the national grid in the related BBC video. http://www.bbc.co.uk/britainfromabove/stories/people/teatimebritain.shtml

Comment: This is the reason why the "earth-hour" thing, where everyone is supposed to switch off for an hour, actually has very little effect. Because the power companies need time to roll back and ramp back up in time for the ensueing surge.. it simply is not worth it. Plus, during sudden demand periods they bring online the oil fired power stations since they are a LOT faster to come on line... QED.. EO is a waste of time.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling : Typical european kettles are 3kW each! (That's the big advantage of 230V.)

Comment: @MartinBonner Well, more often 2.5 or 2.8, rather than 3, at least in .uk.  This is mostly because 3kW is around the rated limit for a single-gang socket, if I recall correctly, so it's good to have some margin.

Comment: @MartinBonner I don't own a kettle, nor watch TV, so I suspect I'm not in the target audience in this case. :-) (I *did* own a kettle several years back, but realized that with how rarely I used it I might as well just use the microwave to heat water, so when it broke, I never replaced it.)

Comment: @Darael : My source is Amazon.co.uk.  The first few hits for "kettle" all said "3kW" or "3000W".  Interestingly, the second time I looked it up, the first two hits said 2200W.  There's no real risk in drawing the full rated 13A for a kettle - you only leave it on for a few minutes at a time.

Comment: @MartinBonner my source is more anecdotal: most of the kettles I've come across have been 2500W or 2800W, though a couple of those were sold online as 3kW in the "title" text, even if the actual description gave the real rating.  And yeah, I'm aware it's not a significant risk, but not all manufacturers seem to be so.

Comment: It's less common now than it used to be, mainly due to the extra TV channels and rise in Internet TV reducing the number of people watching live etc - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TV_pickup

Comment: @MartinBonner they're probably 3kW at the old nominal voltage of 240V, which works out to 2.8kW at a more typical 230V. ([UK/EU voltage specs](http://www.schneider-electric.co.uk/en/faqs/FA144717/))

Comment: Um, actually, the *nominal* voltage changed, but if you get out an AVO and stick it in a UK socket, it will still register 240V.  (They just fudged the errors that equipment was required to work with so that UK and Continental voltages were both acceptable.)

Comment: For those who don't know: The UK used to be on 240V and Europe on 220V, part of Britain's integration into the EU systems means we're now all on 230V.

Comment: I am not quite sure if these mechanisms are not just always on (standby) and wil be triggered by just about any coordinated surge. Also note that the spike might be made much harder, the kettle switching is done over the course of many seconds, maybe minutes.

Comment: @Separatrix Not really, it's what Marin said. The actual voltages remained, we just call them "230V with an acceptable 10V error" now.

Comment: All being turned in within a few minutes or even seconds of each other is nothing like coordinating them all to switch on at the same nanosecond via IoT crap and GPS time synchronization.

Comment: The video isn't playable because it requires Flash Player, and I'm not about to let that get into my computer.

Comment: One of the power stations built to handle this TV pickup is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dinorwig_Power_Station, this station can respond in seconds to any spike. A very interesting read.

Answer (score 8):

It shouldn't work.

- First, there are circuit breakers in flats and houses. These, they could disable, but
- then, you have breakers outside flats, usually one per building section, like staircase. If you try to draw more than you are allowed, it'll break your circuit. But what if it isn't fast enough?
- You will have a breakers and monitoring tools at the transformer station, on the stage that transform medium voltage to low one you use in your flat. Often  this is the first step where you can encounter active protection and management devices.

And so on. Power grid further away from end user is actively managed and monitored. If these countermeasures fail, you will have a

## [Cascading power failure](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascading_failure)

Looking at the examples, for problems like this you need a lightning storm, human error in setting up the protection system, software bug etc.

On the other hand, in [India this happened in 2012](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/2012_India_blackouts), just the way you want it. What was the exact conditions no one knows, but it appears as unusually large power consumption in unusually short time. Of course, power grid there was not a state of the art, so you would need to go faster, stronger and overall larger scale to get this done in more modern system. Can't tell you exactly, because simulations say it shouldn't be possible, and we don't have many real life examples to extrapolate from.

Comment: Also happened around 2000, when Imperial College London was testing its tera(?)watt laser and knocked out half of London. I can't find a citation anywhere, so I didn't post it as an answer, but they were connected directly to the transmission grid without the protections normal distribution grids have

Comment: @nzaman but OP don't want direct approach, I think. Anyway, I'll include it... If and only if I'll find decent article about it.

Comment: The circuit breakers in buildings are irrelevant though: the proposed 3kW is right at standard 13A fuse capacity in 230V regions. Mains circuit breakers are (here in the UK) typically 20-30A for a single floor worth of sockets, with a 30A breaker for an electric oven/hob.  If I wished to participate in an attack on the electric system, the limiting factor for me (and most ordinary people) would be the 60A master breaker, which is nearly 14kW. I have no idea what fuses/breakers are like in e.g. the USA, but it *must* allow substantial power flow.

Comment: @frodoskywalker only irrelevant if they want to only use one / few per building. When it's a lot, these still gets tripped.

Comment: Breakers don't trip on *change* in power consumption, just exceeding limits - which is going to be quite hard to do in a domestic environment. Unless you start shorting out at the point of entry into the house, at which point you're burning the city down instead.

Comment: @pjc50 3kW alone can trip some breakers in my flat. A couple of 3kW devices would almost certainly trip them (I can't bake, vacuum, use washing machine, dishwasher, and use belt grinder at the same time in my flat). Too much in one building would trip building's breakers. At least where I live. It sometimes happen, especially before holidays when everyone wash, bake and clean. And there you have active monitoring systems that indeed can and would react to change.

Comment: The smallest electrical service encountered in the USA is 3kW. (30 amps at 110 volts) Anything installed since World War II will be at least 12kW and the vast majority of the older installations have been replaced. 24kW is the norm for new construction and 48kW service is not uncommon. To get to 3kW in the USA you would have to plug in two or three toasters. The only difficulty I see is that branch circuits here cut out at 1.8 to 2.4 kW, so you would have to get the participants to identify and use outlets on separate branch circuits.

Comment: @DavidC I see no mention about USA in the question, and world is much, much bigger than the USA.

Comment: Higher up in the discussion @frodoskywalker wondered about fusing levels in the USA. My comment provides this information.

Comment: Around here in germany with a bit of effort it should be no problem for the average house to produce a load of 40kW and with somewhat bigger installations you get 60-70kW easily, you just need the proper devices which are not that hard to get hold of. Also note that breakers will not instantly pop when the current goes over the limit (so when your breaker pops when you plug in a 3kW kettle, there is something wrong) but when it is over that for a time. From a 16A breaker I can draw 20A for several seconds, maybe minutes just fine.

Comment: @PlasmaHH depends on breakers, too. There are fast ones. As far as I remember ones I use for light allow some "overdraw" to allow starters to work, and high-powered ones allow much less kick (because, for example, oven does not need such a high boost when it starts). But these are details. If it isn't stopped at breakers, then it is at the stages with active management and protection systems. Unless, of course, it isn't.

Comment: @Mołot: Just check the datasheet of your favorite circuit breaker. Trip levels are not precise; for a mere 50% overload the thermal tripping even for fast ones can vary between 10s and 120s for the same model.

Comment: @frodoskywalker Small houses are usually at 12kW, medium-sized at 24kW.

Comment: @nzaman I call bull on this. Magpie, which is under Blackett labs produces peak power in the Terawatt range. That is connected to the electrical grid by a standard 13amp BS1363 plug. Last I checked Blackett isn't directly connected to the grid.

Comment: @Aron: Hearsay from someone who was in the Physics department at the time; like I said, I couldn't find any citations

Answer (score 6):

Cascade failures are no joke: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Northeast_blackout_of_2003

So how could we engineer one? How big is a [500 sq km area](http://www.bluebulbprojects.com/MeasureOfThings/results.php?comp=area&unit=km2&amt=500&sort=pr&p=1)? How many people are involved in this? That's about a third of London or two Birminghams. Let's say you have 2m people. UK *peak* consumption is very roughly 1kW per person, so your city uses 2GW or half of Drax.

You want to disrupt this.

How much power-delta is required? Let's say 10%. That would require 67,000 people switching on 3kW devices. That seems like quite a lot of people to me, easily enough to engage in more direct action.

Edit: note that you don't necessarily have to switch all of them *on*. If you can switch off enough load simultaneously enough ("load shedding"), this will cause the local voltage to exceed limits for a short time and trip out the substations - causing more load shedding.

If you've got really good control over the on/off timing, you could try oscillating. Exploit the LC resonance in the largest power line leading to the city?

Answer (score 5):

500 square km is a small city... or at least, my city is smaller than that. So, I searched news archives for instances of blackout because of overload of the local power station...

I found one such incident: it happened during a test because of which the power plant was running at a fourth of its capacity. While the test was running, a connection to another power station failed, leaving the local power station with all the demand. The system did shut down automatically. Power was restored 20 minutes afterwards.

So, the normal demand was too much for a fourth of the capacity of this single power station when there was no connection to other power stations for backup.

The conditions for this failure are very unlikely... it is expected that the power plant will have enough capacity to supply any foreseeable peak of demand, and second even if it can't handle the capacity it should be able to pull power from the rest of the national network.

So, even if you manage to multiply the demand of the houses and buildings on the city (which would then make the local circuit breakers fail instead of the whole urban area), so that you can cause a peak power demand beyond its capacity... the power plant should be able to rely on the rest of the national network (which you didn't sabotage).

Answer (score 4):

## Maybe, but there would be easier ways on such small scale

As Mołot mentions, cascading power failures are a real threat. However those usually concern much larger areas. Here is an example from Europe, November 4, 2006.

[The Day Wind Power Nearly Blew Out Europe](http://nuclearpoweryesplease.org/blog/2008/12/13/the-day-wind-power-nearly-blew-out-europe/).

So if your saboteur times things right, preferably when conditions are at their extremes in terms of load and when a big change is not expected, then yes... if they have hacked every "smart" home and for instance suddenly turn off the main power switch in the houses, then flick them on again, then they can perhaps instigate a failure.

But 500 square kilometers is a square about 22 km on the side, or a circle 25 km across. That is not a very large area. And it would probably be quite easy to just shed the troublesome grid sections restore power to others fairly quickly, no more than 15 minutes or so.

However...

Since the area is quite small, it would be easy for the saboteurs to just map the incoming power lines. Unless the area in question has local power production, attacking the power lines will flick the switch on the entire area. This can be done by bringing down the towers — even though you said "no explosives" there are other ways — or by propelling a chain or similar over them to cause a massive short-circuit.

Comment: I think the idea was to not do anything obviously illegal.

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann Sabotaging critical infrastructure for the sake of causing such disruptions is **very** illegal. "Yeah but we were only flicking switches" is not an excuse. Intent and effect is all you need here... and - ta-dah!! - you just committed sabotage.

Comment: @MichaelK It may be inconvenient to prosecute people for making tea. It also is probably much easier to talk people into flipping switches than smashing things.

Comment: @notstoreboughtdirt Does not matter: it is still sabotage and you are the instigator. Not only that but talking thousands of people into it, you have created thousands of witnesses. And since far from all **like** the idea of having some fanboi of Anonymous playing vigilante in their area, knocking out their power this in turn means that the police will probably have advance warning of your ploy, as will the power utility. As a general rule: your probability of keeping a secret is inverse to the square of the number of people aware of it.

Answer (score 3):

[Not only is this possible](https://www.wired.com/2016/02/how-to-hack-the-power-grid-through-home-air-conditioners/), [it already happens](http://www.cnn.com/2010/TECH/innovation/08/09/smart.grid/). (two different links there). I am going to take it that you don't live on the US eastern grid where rolling brownouts/blackouts happen during the summer.

Answer (score 1):

## It is a real danger, especially where I live.

And Why? Because [the government has installed these, in almost all households, as part of their "Residential Load Management Campaign"](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwiHoLXsgIrwAhVSoVwKHXLWDN4QFjABegQICBAD&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.eskom.co.za%2Fsites%2Fidm%2FDocuments%2FRLMFAQ.pdf&usg=AOvVaw3ysrXkPXxlIvl4_M1I9UsF)
Basically, it is a remote-controlled switch for the electrical water heaters "Geysers" that every single household relies upon for their hot water. If allows the power company to remotely switch on or off the water heaters, via signals propagated along the electric lines that power these devices.

So, you have about 17 million households, all on the same (state-owned) power grid. Every household with a 3600w (some 6000w) electrical device that can be remotely triggered by one signal from the power company.

Switching all of them off for a couple hours (so they cool, and are below their thermostat temperature), then switching all of them on simultaneously, will impose a 61 Gigawatt power pull on the network in an instant.
On a grid that has a *total*, all-sources-summed, power generation capacity of 58Gw.
Normal operating load closer to 34-36Gw.

Imagine if some hacker triggers all these devices on at the same time!

Answer (score 0):

3kW per household is not much, I do not think it will cause a large area blackout. It might cause some on the edge transformators to stop functioning. For reference 3kW is a vacuum cleaner and a hair dryer running at the same time (maybe plus a couple of lights). Unless you are already running couple of other devices eating 3kW, you are out of luck. If you want to overload the system, you should care about turning all that the house breaker could handle, not necessarily at the same time. If the grid is well connected and the event is local, the system might stay up or you could take down quite large sections of it, not just the immediate area.